# Why does python not recognise my side = TOP and fill = x attribute in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, pack

I have a frame inside a tkinter grid cell. Within the frame I want to pack 2 labels.

However when I try and apply a side to pack or fill I get a name error such as

NameError: name 'TOP' is not defined

I've tried consulting tutorials online and my Tkinter book but still cannot see what the error is. I have tried caps, lowercase and with quotation marks around the side and fill option but still no joy.

```
import tkinter as tk

MAINFONT = "Marcellus SC"
SUBFONT = "Oswald"
TEXT_SIZE = 12
SPACER = 37 #this  is the padding beween cells

root = tk.Tk()

#Other rows have been established

question_1_frm = tk.Frame(border = 1)
question_1_frm.grid(row = 3, column = 2, sticky = "NW")
first_question_lbl = tk.Label(question_1_frm, text = question_1, font = (MAINFONT, TEXT_SIZE), bg = "white", wraplength = 403*scale_factor_x, justify="left")
first_question_lbl.pack()
first_answer_lbl = tk.Label(question_1_frm, font =(MAINFONT,TEXT_SIZE))
first_answer_lbl.pack(side =TOP, fill=X)

root.mainloop()
```

I wanted both first_question_lbl and first_answer_lbl to be packed into the parent frame, the former under the latter but I keep getting.

NameError: name 'TOP' is not defined

from side=TOP

I get a similar message for just fill=x

Comment: `TOP` is declared in the `tkinter` module, which you imported as `tk` - so you'd access it as `tk.TOP`.  Any code you saw that used `TOP` by itself must have done `from tkinter import *`, which brings in all of the defined names from the module indiscriminately.

Comment: superb! tk.TOP and tk.X work fine now. Many thanks

Comment: you can use strings `top`, `x`, `both`, etc. and they work always. Variable `tk.TOP` has value `"top"`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Jason

TOP is declared in the tkinter module, which you imported as tk - so you'd access it as tk.TOP. Any code you saw that used TOP by itself must have done from tkinter import *, which brings in all of the defined names from the module indiscriminately. – jasonharper

tk.TOP and tk.X work fine now.